# Comparing multiple dictionaries and generating another dictionary using python

Tags: python, dictionary, generator

I have two dictionaries like:

```
dict1 = {'Ron': ['Ronaldo', 'Ronald', 'Ron', 'Ronny'],
         'John': ['Johnny', 'john', 'johnny Bravo'],
         'Hard': ['Hardy', 'Hardy Boys', 'Hardness']}

dict2 = {'Ronald': ['America', 'New York'],
         'Johnny': ['Canada', 'Ottawa']}
```

I want to compare both dictionaries and extract the **'key'** of **dict1** and the **value** of **dict2**, **if and only if** the **'key'** of **dict2** matches the **value** of **dict1**! Like:

```
resultant_dict = {'Ron' : ['America', 'New York'],
                  'John' : ['Canada', 'Ottawa']}
```

I have tried nested loops and is able to get the desired dict but can please someone help me doing this by generators in python!  Thanks
NOTE: the KEY of DICT2 can only be ONE in DICT1'S VALUE!

Comment: Please show your attempt to do this?

Comment: Also, this question isn't well defined - can a key from `dict2` only be in one of `dict1`'s values? If not, then what should happen in that scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, reverse the `dict1` dictionary:

```
rev = {v:k for k,vs in dict1.iteritems() for v in vs}
```

`rev` is now:

```
{'Hardness': 'Hard',
 'Hardy': 'Hard',
 'Hardy Boys': 'Hard',
 'Johnny': 'John',
 'Ron': 'Ron',
 'Ronald': 'Ron',
 'Ronaldo': 'Ron',
 'Ronny': 'Ron',
 'john': 'John',
 'johnny Bravo': 'John'}
```

Then map keys from `dict2` using this dictionary:

```
resultant_dict = {rev[k]:v for k,v in dict2.iteritems()}
```

returning

```
{'John': ['Canada', 'Ottawa'], 'Ron': ['America', 'New York']}
```